# Kokkova or kokkora carved on ivory

Tags: cross-linguistic

My question is to try to find the origin of the word kokkova. I have an antique/primitive pin made of ivory which if  I had to guess would say that it is walrus but not 100% sure. It is scrimshawed with a basic line design and the word Kokkova. (it is possible that the "v" is an "r") I thought it could be an inuit piece but again unable to say definitively. Thanks, Devo

Comment: Welcome! Have you Googled the word? I get a place in Greece. What else have you done to research this?

Comment: I think this is the kind of language question that is not a linguistics question but rather one suited to [the "Languages" proposed SE site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61823/languages?referrer=CsTIE1DOEV2o7tQ8CcbOfA2). Consider committing to it.